# How can I compress similar rows?

Tags: database, compression

I store a very large number of blobs of varying size (~10-100kb) in a key-value database. Rows are appended, never deleted.

Since many of the blobs are very similar, it would be possible to compress them to a high degree if they were concatenated. However, that's not trivial to apply here, given that the data is in different rows.

Is there a reasonably easy way to still compress them, or at least remove part of the redundancy?

Comment: Storing BLOBS in a database is NEVER a good practice. You should store the PATHS to those files.

Comment: @Bob I expect 180M blobs of, on average, 20kb, which I need to access by 2 different keys, and sometimes filter by certain properties of the blob - isn't a database preferable over files there, if only for extensibility for more complex scenarios? It's not like I'm storing large images there.

Comment: I woldn't bloat my database with BLOBS. Specially a SQLite database.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of it either, for sure! But do you really prefer having 180M files? And then manually doing a `select * from foo where content like '%string%'` or similar? It does not sound feasible to me.

Comment: If so... no, I can't think of any other way than using these BLOBS. But I can't even think of any way to "compress" them.

Comment: @BobMalooga Yes, me either - hence this question :)

Comment: Maybe there's no way to? I mean, if you have to search for a *substring* in *compressed* files... then the search string must be compressed as well. Or am I getting the whole thing wrong?

Comment: @BobMalooga Let's ignore the search queries for a while, I think it's already difficult enough to compress the rows without it. I'm hoping for pointers for further research, and maybe I can make more complex queries work later, too. The thing is, the file (as a whole, not individual rows by themselves) could surely be compressed to <5% size, so the potential gains are significant.

Comment: So, you mean to store ZIPPED BLOBS? If so, your affirmation to make a `select * from foo where content like '%string%'` is not realistic.

Comment: @BobMalooga That was just an example, probably not the best one, as it makes other problems more prominent. What I'm most concerned about at the moment is the sheer number of rows, which I think makes storing as files impractical. Any further queries will need to be dealt with as fit, but that's of minor importance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are compression libraries which use a *dictionary*, i.e. a common library of pre-calculated data. This dictionary helps to compress data shared by many items only once. To create the dictionary, usually a sample of the items to compress is given to the compression library so that it may derive a useful bag of common data from it.

This would help to compress all items individually while maintaining a compression rate close to a single, "solid" archive.

zstd is an example of such a library, doubtlessly there are many others.